# Reference about the proof of this proposition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

``Let $M$ be a finite dimensional Hopf algebra with antipode $S$ and let
$M^*$ be the dual bialgebra. Recalls that $x^* \in M^*$ is a primitive in $M^*$, then $x^*$ is a derivation of $M$. ''

I am finding a reference for the proof of the above proposition. Thank you very much for  your hints!

Comment: The primitivity of $x^*$ means $\Delta\left(x^*\right) = x^* \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes x^*$. This is an equality in $M^* \otimes M^*$. Now send it over into $\left(M\otimes M\right)^*$ via the canonical homomorphism (which is an isomorphism since $M$ is finite-dimensional, but this doesn't even matter), and apply both sides to $a \otimes b \in M \otimes M$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's done.